# jQuery plugin callback parameter not passing

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to create a plugin with callbacks, however I can't pass a parameter to the callback function.

I am calling the callback within the plugin as follows:

```
console.log(response.data);
base.options['onFinished'].call(response.data);
```

As expected response.data is propogated with the correct data, however on the other end where I defined the callback:

```
$ele.app({
   onFinished: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
   }
);
```

It is being called, however data is "undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
options.onFinished.call(this,response.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `call` should be the value used for `this` in the called function, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

```
base.options['onFinished'].call(this, response.data);
```

Note you can choose what you want the context set to. Typically you would want it to be the element that triggered the event that is being handled.  The sample assumes that is also the the context of the currently executing plugin function.